# How to output the results of a SQL query into a report form table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an the following table fields:

```
Invitations (user_id, type, created_at, completed_at)
```

I'm currently able to obtain last week's invitation conversation rate by running the following query and manually computing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM invitations
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
AND user_id != 1
AND type = 'email'
ORDER BY completed_at, created_at
```

Is it possible with SQL to output more of a report... Something that returns:

```
LAST WEEK | Total Invitations | Invitations Completed | % Conversion    
          | 100               | 50                    | 50%  
TWO WEEKS | Total Invitations | Invitations Completed | % Conversion    
          | 100               | 60                    | 60%
```

Is something like this possible with SQL or do I need to create this with application logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to aggregate using `count()` and do a `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 'LAST WEEK' `Period`,
       count(created_at) `Total Invitations`,
       count(completed_at) `Invitations completed`,
       concat(count(completed_at) / count(created_at) * 100, '%') `% Conversion` 
       FROM invitations
       WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) + 6 DAY
             AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) - 1 DAY
             AND user_id <> 1
             AND type = 'email'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TWO WEEKS' `Period`,
       count(created_at) `Total Invitations`,
       count(completed_at) `Invitations completed`,
       concat(count(completed_at) / count(created_at) * 100, '%') `% Conversion` 
       FROM invitations
       WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) + 13 DAY
             AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) - 1 DAY
             AND user_id <> 1
             AND type = 'email';
```

`count(completed_at)` does only count the rows, where `completed_at` isn't null. I assume that `completed_at` is null if and only if the invitation isn't completed. `count(created_at)` works analog. But I assume there are no null values in that column (and if they were, those rows won't match the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, so they aren't even candidates for counting). `UNION ALL` just unites the two result sets (without eliminating duplicates, which aren't in there anyway, as at least the `Period` differs).

Comment: That is incredible - thank you